# Binding to TableLayout in Mvvmcross

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Is there any example of binding any sort of collection to a TableLayout in android? I keep receiving the message/warning that binding failed for attribute ItemSource LocationQuantities. All of the other bindings to the view model work as normal, but the list doesn't bind to the TableLayout. At first I thought my problem was binding to a dictionary but I was able to bind to a dictionary with other Mvx layouts (listview etcs.)

I can't seem to find in any of the N+ code examples or anywhere else on the web where a TableLayout is actually used in an mvvmcross app. I'm sure I'm just doing something stupid simple wrong here.

```
<Mvx.MvxTableLayout
        p1:id="@+id/PartLocationQtyTable"
        p1:layout_width="fill_parent"
        p1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        p1:layout_below="@id/PartDetailPriceLayout"
        p1:padding="5.0dp"
        local:MvxBind="ItemSource LocationQuantities"
        />
```

I've tried the above as well as with a custom template. The above example just uses a list of strings.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what 'my problem' is? Currently I don't really understand what you are or are not seeing, or what you expected to see. Thanks

Comment: @Stuart Sorry for not explaining a bit further, I have edited question...

Comment: @theMothaShip - I don't suppose you could provide details about how you got the template working? I'm trying to use MvxTableLayout as well and have had zero luck so far :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only obvious problem I can see with your code is that it uses `ItemSource` whereas all the `list`-based layouts use `ItemsSource` - see [MvxTableLayout.cs#L89](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxTableLayout.cs#L89)

Beyond that, I guess you'll also want to make sure that your templates for `TableLayout` are `TableRow`s - so that they can be loaded as rows. Obviously we can't see your item templates currently as you've not included them in the question.

I've got to admit `TableLayout` isn't something I've ever personally used in a production project - just not something I've yet needed to use.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'm going to try this and will update with the results... Thanks for all the time and effort put into MVVMCross -- It has been pretty good to me so far!

Comment: The issue was 100% with the fact that I was using ItemSource instead of ItemsSource... Thanks for the info again!